# How do I get Google Log Viewer (Logs Explorer) to show me GCE VM instance names

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm using the python API for google.cloud.logging, and my log messages show up in Google Logging viewer console page, but I can only see the  VM instance id numbers, whereas I want to view the instance names.

```
import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()

logging.basicConfig(filename='insights-server.log', 
                    format='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', 
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    filemode='w',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I am running my Python app inside a container, launched with something like this:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container hqm-insights-server \
  --container-image us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/staging-335116/pyleela/insights:${VERSION} \
  --zone us-east1-b \
  --container-env-file insights-env.txt \
  --scopes bigquery,pubsub,storage-rw,logging-write,monitoring-write \
 --metadata google-logging-enabled=true
```

So that worker should have the instance name "hqm-insights-server".
However in the Google Log Explorer I only see entries like this:

[log viewer lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsWyP.png)
With just the  VM instance-id, not the  VM instance-name.

The JSON log messages themselves do not seem to contain the instance name.

I swear I've seen instance names show up in the logs in other cases when I used the
python google logging API. Anyone have an idea how I can get them to get sent / show up?

Also is there some issue with the logger errors I'm seeing (second JSON blob below) about
"Unable to export to Monitoring service because..."

```
{
  "insertId": "63ugtifakjv5q",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "message": "looping listening for messages",
    "python_logger": "root"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance",
    "labels": {
      "instance_id": "2166453014221653516",
      "project_id": "staging-335116",
      "zone": "projects/716348246245/zones/us-east1-b"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-01-24T16:24:10.031698Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/staging-335116/logs/python",
  "sourceLocation": {
    "file": "pyleela/insights/InsightServerPubSub.py",
    "line": "319",
    "function": "msg_listener_loop"
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-01-24T16:24:10.045862321Z"
}
```

```
{
  "insertId": "wx3dqzwc4kd1m2i82",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "message": "Unable to export to Monitoring service because: GaxError RPC failed, caused by 8:received trailing metadata size exceeds limit. debug_error_string:{\"created\":\"@1643041411.157005999\",\"description\":\"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.204.95:443\",\"file\":\"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc\",\"file_line\":1062,\"grpc_message\":\"received trailing metadata size exceeds limit\",\"grpc_status\":8}\n",
    "cos.googleapis.com/container_name": "stackdriver-logging-agent",
    "cos.googleapis.com/stream": "stderr",
    "cos.googleapis.com/container_id": "3520f78eef6feafea6365d661bd0bba402400e5d474d20ac73e06adb4c42e49a"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_instance",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "staging-335116",
      "zone": "us-east1-b",
      "instance_id": "2166453014221653516"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-01-24T16:23:31.159938926Z",
  "labels": {
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "3520f78eef6f"
  },
  "logName": "projects/staging-335116/logs/cos_containers",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-01-24T16:23:36.608521825Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (!?) you'll need to use the `instance_id` as a key and lookup the instance names using the Compute Engine API; the instance ID is its unique identifier and other metadata such as the instance name may change (and be non-unique).

See Compute Engine [`instances.get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get). There's an [example](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get#examples) at the end of the page.

For efficiency, it may be better to use [`instances.list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list) and cache the id:name mapping **but** the indirection reflects the fact that you can rename instances without changing their ID; so you're cached names **could** become invalidated.

###### Update

Thinking about this some more, it is slightly curious that Compute Engine uses unique (by project?) IDs for instances but Compute Engine's API (continues to require) the `zone` to `get` or `list` instances; if the ID is unique (for the project) then the `zone` should be redundant.

However, assuming you need the `zone`, you can combine the `resource.labels[instance_id]` and (parsing depending on your `logName` choice) `resource.labels[zone]` to get the `zone` sufficient to issue the Compute Engine `get` or `list`.

> **NOTE** The error you're receiving in the 2nd (`logName` = `cos_containers`) for the `stackdriver-logging-agent` is not within your control and is possibly a Google issue. Cloud Logging uses gRPC and, for some reason, the call being logged for the container includes trailing headers that exceed what Cloud Logging is willing to accept.

Comment: Are you saying I can formulate a  query , joining the instance id with instances list , using the Google Log Explorer query language itself?   Or are you proposing I do that inside my application to look up the instance name?   

I tried adding some metadata to the gcloud compute instances launch command, using the --labels arg  (see below) but that doesn't appear anywhere in my log  messages JSON 

  --labels component-type=insights-server,component-name=insights-server-1

Comment: You may be able to do it using the Monitoring Query Language (MQL) but I'd perform the "join" in Python. A log entry includes the unique instance ID and Compute Engine API is a way to `get` other instance metadata from the instance ID. Because the logs will likely repeat the instance IDs, you can cache these (hashmap|dict) on first lookup to save making the same Compute Engine `get` repeatedly.

Comment: did you solve it @henry-minsky?

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to get the instance name of the container host to get sent in log data, the only workaround I have found so far is that I can at least get the logName to be set to a string from my application's code, so I do something like this in my python app that's running in the container image:

```
    import google.cloud.logging_v2
    client = google.cloud.logging_v2.Client()
    from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, setup_logging
    handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name="insights-server")
    setup_logging(handler)
```

That ends up sending { logName: "insights-server" } in the JSON log messages, and then I can have Log Explorer display it for each log event.

But I still don't have a way to have it show the actual instance name of the host machine; it gives me the instance-id, but that is just a number that isn't mnemonic in any way.

Since we can name our instances when we launch them,  we'd like to use instance names like 'insights-server-1', 'insights-server-2', etc to make it easy to see at a glance which type of worker is sending the event.